# How to stop ticks to moveout of axis in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a similar requirement and created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roytirthadeep/gLn95dwm/)

I am trying to make use of tickPositions to set the xAxis ticks but the problem is the ticks are moving out of the chart window. Can, any one please help me with this. Also, please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
        useUTC: false
      }
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
          load: function() {

            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            var series = this.series[0];
            var xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
            setInterval(function() {
              var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                y = Math.random();
              series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
              xAxis.options.tickPositions.push(x);
            }, 1000);
          }
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPositions: [],
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.value);
          }
        },
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
          value: 0,
          width: 1,
          color: '#808080'
        }]
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
          return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
            Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        }
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function() {
          // generate an array of random data
          var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;

          for (i = -10; i <= 0; i += 1) {
            data.push({
              x: time + i * 1000,
              y: Math.random()
            });
          }
          return data;
        }())
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: incorrect fiddle link. What do you mean by ticks, all I can see one point comes in through right and other moves out from left, you don't want that ?

Comment: try this [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/roytirthadeep/gLn95dwm) ... by ticks I mean the tickIntervals

Comment: So ticks should stay still at the same time, but points should be shifted, that is correct?

Comment: @SebastianBochan .. sorry for the confusion... actually in the fiddle if u notice... after 12 seconds or so... the points are shifted fine but the ticks are not shifted properly...i.e. it goes out of the chart window (at bottom left corner)... please let me know

Comment: Remove a empty array in tickPositions, fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/gLn95dwm/1/

Comment: @SebastianBochan... actually I kept the tickPositions array as empty initially..because I want the ticks on x-axis only when there is point in the series...which I am doing in the load event...

Comment: Instead of placing empty array and then xAxis.options.tickPositions.push(x), call only [xAxis.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update) in your load event.

Comment: could you please provide an example for the same... I am not getting how to .... actually my main intention is not to show any ticks when there are no points (or markers) and that to dynamically I need to do that... because as it is time series there might be certain duration for which I will not get any data (say for 3-4 seconds)..Thanks for you help in advance

Comment: @SebastianBochan .... could you please suggest some work around.. I have tried so many ways but I am not able to achieve the requirement....my requirement is, in case of dynamic chart I don't want to show the ticks where marker is not present.... i.e. if I call a series.addPoint after every 5 seconds (say).. I want to show the ticks for those points not the others... 

Or any work around..like how to handle this scenario

Comment: Use a tickPositioner which allows to use function to print ticks in custom places. Let me know if you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gLn95dwm/4/

Comment: @SebastianBochan...  yes, I tried tickPositioner....but I see you have used a concept of xAxis.customMax (which I was missing) ... could you please elaborate on this point ...so that I get a better understanding of what I was doing wrong... Also, I can't wait to try out your solution... :)

Comment: customMax is a value of xAxis max, before loading a new points. In that way you can return ticks only for new values.